# What is the most ideal approach to check date values with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

A specific column of my table is hour_init and the other one is hour_end. I'm trying to build a check constraint that determines if both hour_init and hour_end follows this rules:

- Rule 1: The format must be HH:MM
- Rule 2: HH must be less than 24
- Rule 3: MM must be less than 59

I have read and/or figured out some approaches but I can't decide what would be the "best practice" or the ideal solution.

Approach 1:

Create the table with 2 columns of type varchar2. Create a check constraint that splits each varchar2 in substrings (after and before ":"), cast the substrings into numbers and check if they follow rule 2 and 3. I don't know how bad or good this method is.

Approach 2:

Create the table with 2 columns of type DATE or TIMESTAMP. Then format those DATEs into HH:MM, then check if the value that is been inserted, its hour and minute follows rule 2 and 3.

What approach should be chosen?

Comment: Why not use type `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`  That's a little more granular than you need, but at least it's correctly typed. Then you can insert 9 hours and 30 minutes (for instance) with the literal `INTERVAL '09:30' HOUR TO MINUTE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, never EVER store date (nor time) values into `VARCHAR2` columns. No advantage, many disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

if you create the columns as DATE or some variant of TIMESTAMP, (depending on the granularity you need) there is nothing to check. Oracle will not let you put an invalid value into a either of those data types. Which is one of many reasons you should NEVER use varchar2 or number to keep date/time.